# Cannon.js is there a way to check if an object is colliding with 2 other objects at the same time?

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio, cannon.js

I'm using Cannon.js to make a game where a ball bounces of of your head and the sides of the screen have boxes as boundaries. when the ball collides with the head it adds one more to the score. ***I want to check if the the ball is colliding with the one of the walls and the head at the same time***, because when this happens I don't want it to add one to the score. does someone know how to create a check for this?

My code:

```
const UIManager = require("./UIManager.js");

var playing = false;

// Create cannon world and setting gravity
const world = new CANNON.World();
world.gravity.set(0, -0.52, 0);

// Create sphere body and setting its shape and properties
var mat1 = new CANNON.Material();

// Radius for the ball object
const Radius = 0.05;

// Radius for the head hitbox
const Radius2 = 0.08;

const BallProp = {
    mass: 2,
    position: new CANNON.Vec3(0, 1.1, 0),
    radius: Radius,
    material: mat1,
    shape: new CANNON.Sphere(Radius),
}

// Add the ball to the physics world
const BallBody = new CANNON.Body(BallProp);
world.addBody(BallBody);

// Create a material for the head hitbox
var HeadMaterial = new CANNON.Material();

// Create ground body and settings its shape and properties
const HeadProp = {
    mass: 0,
    position: new CANNON.Vec3(0, 0, 0),
    radius: Radius2,
    material: HeadMaterial,
    shape: new CANNON.Sphere(Radius2),
}
const HeadBody = new CANNON.Body(HeadProp);

// Rotate the ground so it is flat (facing upwards)
const angle = -Math.PI / 2;
const xAxis = new CANNON.Vec3(1, 0, 0);
HeadBody.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(xAxis, angle);

// Add the hitbox to the physics world
world.addBody(HeadBody);

// Create a new material for the walls
var WallMaterial = new CANNON.Material();

// Create walls and settings its shape and properties
const WallProp1 = {
    mass: 0,
    position: new CANNON.Vec3(-1.19, 0.6, 0),
    material: WallMaterial,
    shape: new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(1, 1, 1)),
}

const WallProp2 = {
    mass: 0,
    position: new CANNON.Vec3(1.19, 0.6, 0),
    material: WallMaterial,
    shape: new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(1, 1, 1)),
}

const Wall1Body = new CANNON.Body(WallProp1);
const Wall2Body = new CANNON.Body(WallProp2);

// Add the walls to the physics world
world.addBody(Wall1Body);
world.addBody(Wall2Body);

// Create a death plane and settings its shape and properties
const deathProps = {
    mass: 0,
    position: new CANNON.Vec3(0, -0.35, 0),
    shape: new CANNON.Plane(),
}
const DeathBody = new CANNON.Body(deathProps);

// Set the rotation correctly
DeathBody.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(xAxis, angle);

// Add the deathplane to the physics world
world.addBody(DeathBody);

// Add new settings to the materials
var mat1_ground = new CANNON.ContactMaterial(HeadMaterial, mat1, { friction: 0.0, restitution: 1});
var mat1_wall = new CANNON.ContactMaterial(WallMaterial, mat1, { friction: 0.0, restitution: 0.65});
world.addContactMaterial(mat1_ground);
world.addContactMaterial(mat1_wall);

// Configure time step for Cannon
const fixedTimeStep = 1.0 / 60.0;
const maxSubSteps = 3;
const timeInterval = 30;
let lastTime;

var score = 0;

//checks for collision with the head hitbox
HeadBody.addEventListener("collide",function(e){
    if(playing)
    {
        score++;
        Diagnostics.log("Bounced amount / Score = " + score);
    }
    else
    {
        BallBody.velocity.set(0,0,0);
        BallBody.position.set(0,1,0);
    }
});

//checks for collision with the death plane
DeathBody.addEventListener("collide",function(e){
    if(playing)
    {
        EndGame(score);
    }
    else
    {
        BallBody.velocity.set(0,0,0);
        BallBody.position.set(0,1,0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this might work: 
step 1 : create a variable `colliding` and set it to false 
step 2 : set `colliding` to false every frame 
step 3 : in headBody event listener, if it collides with the ball, set `colliding` to true 
step 4 : in deathPlane, check if it collides with the ball and if `colliding` is true, it means the ball touches both 
(you might have to switch, i.e. setting `colliding` in deathPlane and checking it in headBody)

That's how i used to check if 2 specific items collide, and that check involved checking 2 collisions at same frame + some other verifications.

If you don't know how to check if a body collides with the ball, the condition is `event.body.id == ballBody.id` with `ballBody` being the body of the ball use for physical calculations.